# Add an object to a sub document list of object Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to append a DOM object to a list of object into a Sub document of my Mongo database. However, so far no avail. Im retrieving the data from an html form in which i grouped the data in objects. I first tried to use a forEach loop, but i kept getting an message saying that the $addToSet is empty, eventhough when i log the Objects im retrieving from the DOM  seems to not be empty. I applied this is same approach, in a put request from a previous route whilst then i had no problem updating the database. This is my first application, im still a noob, so you help would be very much appreciated.

```js
// my database Schema
// schema for images
var images = new Schema(
  {
    title: String,
    description: String,
    link: String
  }
);

// shema lower for the tes dictionary
var days = new Schema({
  day: Number,
  route: String,
  distance: Number,
  description: String,
  imageamount: Number,
  images: Array(images),

})

// schema upper for the test dictionary
var tourSchema  = new Schema({
  date: String,
  thumbnail: String,
  categories: Array,
  title: String,
  locations: Array,
  duration: Number,
  generalDescription: String,
  dayInfo: Array(days),
});

var Tour = mongoose.model("Tour", tourSchema);

// this is the code Im using to update the db

app.put("/tours/:id/dayinfo/images", (req, res) => {
  Tour.findById(req.params.id, (err, tour) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
        for( var i = 0; i < tour.dayInfo.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 1; j <= tour.dayInfo[i].imageamount; j++){
            Tour.updateOne({_id: tour.dayInfo[i]._id}, {$addToSet: { images: req.body["images" + String(Number(i+1)) + String(j)] } },{upsert: true}, (err, updatedImages) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                  console.log(updatedImages);
              }
            })
          }
          console.log("updated imagess for images ");
        };
        res.redirect("/");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
  <form class="some-form"  action="/tours/<%= tour._id %>/dayinfo/images?_method=PUT" method="POST">

             <% tour.dayInfo.forEach ( (day) => { %>
                  <header>
                    <h3>Images of <b>Day  <%= day.day %><b></h3>
                  </header>
                  <hr>

                   <% for (var i = 1; i <= day.imageamount; i++ ) { %>
                    <!-- tour info -->
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="images<%= day.day %><%= i %>[title]" value="" placeholder="Short title of image" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="images<%= day.day %><%= i %>[description]" value="" placeholder="Short description of image" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="images<%= day.day %><%= i %>[link]" value="" placeholder="link of image" class="form-control">
                    <br>
                   <% } %>
          <% }); %>

          <input type="submit" name="" value="SAVE" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        </form>
```

```js
// this code seems to work, yet when applying the same approach for a deeper laying doc, it does not work i get a message saying that '\'addToSet'\' is empty.

/ update({_id: ObjectId("5bf404f0fd415e077e849694")}, {$addToSet: {dayInfo:  {day: 8} }}, {upsert: true} )
app.put("/tours/:id/dayinfo", (req, res) => {
    Tour.findById(req.params.id, (err, tour) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          for (var i = 1; i <= tour.duration; i++){
            Tour.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$addToSet: { dayInfo: req.body["dayInfo" + String(i)] } }, {upsert: true}, (err, updatedDayInfo) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                  console.log(req.body["dayInfo" + String(i)]);
              }
            })
          console.log("successfully updated day " + i );
          }
        }
    })
    res.redirect("/tours/" + req.params.id  + "/dayinfo/images" );
  });
```

Comment: @OttoGutierrez That's not the problem. There is a `for` loop where the callbacks are not being awaited before it completes. You *"can"* learn about how to implement things so callbacks or promises are run "serially" or at least respect loop completion. Or you can learn to write all the requests at once with [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/). Since the latter means just **one** call to the database and no need to control multiple async calls, it usually makes most sense to understand that one first. But learning async control also helps.

Comment: @OttoGutierrez the list is actually an array

Comment: @NeilLunn , thank you i did not know this part yet, im going to research and find out how to impolment loops so callback s are run serially